# Using BackgroundWorker to retrieve details of last selected item from a list

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, backgroundworker

In my application I have a DataGrid that is populated from a database. When I click one of the items, its details are retrieved and passed to UI. Getting item details is a coslty operation so I use a BackgroundWorker to handle it. When I select another item during the retrieval, I would like to abort current operation and start another one using new item id. What;s the best way to do it? I tried to put this in DataGrid CellContentClick hanlder:

```
if(worker.IsBusy)
{
    worker.CancelAsync();
}
```

but I always get details of first selected item.

Comment: You'll have to post the code for DoWork (cancel handling) and Completed events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out myself. Firstly i scattered following blocks all over worker_DoWork handler:

```
if(worker.CancellationPending)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    return;
}
```

I also prevented execution of worker.RunWorkerAsync(), when worker.CancellationPending is true. To achieve my goal I added the following code to my RunWorkerCompleted handler:

```
if(!e.Cancelled)
{
    //update UI
}
else
{
    //retrieve details of new item
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don't check for the [BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancellationpending%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) while retrieving the item data.

You will have to do something like this:

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do not access the form's BackgroundWorker reference directly.
        // Instead, use the reference provided by the sender parameter.
        BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        // Extract the argument.
        int arg = (int)e.Argument;

        // Start the time-consuming operation.
        e.Result = TimeConsumingOperation(bw, arg);

        // If the operation was canceled by the user, 
        // set the DoWorkEventArgs.Cancel property to true.
        if (bw.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

See also [How to: Run an Operation in the Background](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hybbz6ke.aspx).

Probably you want to place several checks for `CancellationPending` in your async code, one after each step that takes a significant amount of time.